# Command shows different results when I login as a user vs su to the user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, users, init.d, path

I'm trying to run a simple command from an init.d script and I'm troubleshooting why the command doesn't work when I run it from my init.d script but works when I run it as my user.

Can someone explain why when I run `nvm --version` as my logged in user it shows a value, but when I `su` to my user it does not know what `nvm` is? This is ultimately the root cause of my init.d script not working I believe.

```
$ whoami
someuser
someuser@node-server1:/var/www/dev$ nvm --version
0.18.0
someuser@node-server1:/var/www/dev$ su - someuser -c "nvm --version"
Password: 
-su: nvm: command not found
```

I noticed this in my .bashrc:

```
export NVM_DIR="/home/someuser/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

Do I somehow need to run this as a command in my init.d script or when I `su` to a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the NVM documentation:

> To activate nvm, you need to source it from your shell:
>   `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh`

So, yes, in order to be able to use nvm, you must first "activate" it before invoking it.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the 'someuser' user's `$PATH` does not have the path where the `nvm` binary is located. To be able to use the command `nvm` you need to add the location of `nvm` binary to that user's path.

Do this:

Run `which nvm` as the user for whom `nvm` command is currently availble. If will show you where the `nvm` command is located. For example, if `which nvm` gives you `/usr/local/nvm/bin/nvm`, then you have to add `/usr/local/nvm/bin` to the path of the user where `nvm` is not currently available. For that, add the following line in the new user's .bashrc.

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/nvm/bin`

Once, its done, log out, log back in, or `source` the .bashrc file and the `nvm` command will be available for the new user.

*For example*: If user 'abc' does not have nvm available, add the `export PATH...` line to /home/abc/.bashrc

Comment: I can use the command `$ nvm use default`, but `$ which nvm` doesn't show anything: `$ nvm use default
Now using node v0.11.14
myuser@node-server1:~$ which nvm`

Answer (score 0):

Where is located the nvm program? To find this out, you can type `whereis nvm`. It looks like this directory is added to the path somewhere inside your .bashrc file.

What you have to know is that "su -c" runs a non-interactive shell. You can check this by looking into $- variable content :

```
# echo $-
himBH
# su -c 'echo $-' - $USER
Mot de passe : 
hBc
```

The 'i' means the shell is currently interactive. Well, in ubuntu, you can notice that your .bashrc file starts with those few lines:

```
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

This means that this file isn't sourced if the $- variable doesn't contain an 'i', i.e  while in an non-interactive shell.

You have two possible workarounds:

1- Run nvm with sudo command instead of su:

```
# sudo -u $USER echo $-
himBH
```

Note that because of sudo's behaviour, you mustn't use quotes.

2- Use nvm's full path to the binary and source the required file:

```
# su -c 'source $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh; /path/to/nvmdir/nvm --version' - $USER
```

Using `nvm` instead of its full path `/path/to/nvmdir/nvm` may be sufficient if $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh is the one updating your $PATH.